# Setting up enviroment variables in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, environment-variables

I am trying to setup up my enviroment variable in my Ubuntu machine. Now i did some research and tryed the method on this question Set environment variable in Ubuntu

Similar question but the thing is I already wrote up the "etc/enviroment" the "etc/profile" and the "etc/bash.bashrc" file to include my variables:

```
JAVA_HOME=/home/glv/information/jdk1.6.0_25/
export JAVA_HOME
BASEDIR=/home/glv/apache-tomcat-6.0.29/  
export BASEDIR
```

However the problem is when i run the startup.sh on apache it still says that the BASEDIR enviroment variable is not setup right and for all I know the JAVA_HOME may not be correct as well. I am using the latest Ubuntu not sure if that a problem or not or if i have to go another way around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to provide some context for this.  How do you run it?  Where do you run it from?  Are the environment variables set in `startup.sh`?  What shell runs `startup.sh`?

Comment: Did you also forget to include a link to another question?

Comment: @Karlson I am running i have tried setting the variables at the "etc/environment" "etc/profile" and "etc/bash.bashrc" and my local .bashrc never tried a startup.sh dont see that file in the 'etc' folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache is controlled in Ubuntu by using the Apache init script, at `/etc/init.d/apache2`. This script is run when you start and stop Apache with commands like:-

```
> sudo service apache2 [start|stop|restart|graceful|etc...]
```

If you look in this init script, you'll see that the environment is set and modified here, by first reading environment variables from the file `/etc/apache2/envvars`. This separate environment is important because the Apache's server process is a seteuid executable, which means that can run with an "effective User ID". On my Ubuntu machine, the Apache processes are run with a user name of 'www-data', even though the root user starts the process. As this is a "system account", it has no default shell or bash environment, and uses none of those files that set your user environment.

So what I think you want to do is put those environment variables in `/etc/apache2/envvars`.

Update:

Apache on Ubuntu has a number of .conf files (in /etc/apache2/ and subdirs) that can also be used to modify the running Apache environment. The configuration files are parsed sequentially, and are all included by the master config file: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

In these conf files, you can use [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html) to modify the environment. Then you will know for sure that the environment is as you want. For example, you can add this to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`:-

```
 SetEnv JAVA_HOME /home/glv/information/jdk1.6.0_25/
```

Comment: What about the JAVA_HOME for all i know it may not be working either.

Comment: Why do you need it if you can't tell if it's working? I'd just put it into /etc/apache2/envvars, keeping it out of /etc/profile, /etc/environment, etc. If you need it in your user environment, then just have it in `~/.bashrc`. To explicitly test what path is being set, I'd write a simple server-side to print the value of these server side variables.
There is another way to set Apache environment variables too. I'll add it to my answer...

Comment: *server-side pre-processed HTML file (e.g [.php](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php8p7.html) or [.shtml](http://www.ssi.su/)

Comment: Also on the Ubuntu machine I am using the    `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and the 
`/etc/init.d/apache2` doesn't exist the files your describing aren't there at all. and there is no apache2 folder on it

Comment: Oh, right. If not apache2.conf, the main config file should be called httpd.conf. What version of Apache do you have installed? On my system (Debian kernel with Ubuntu packages), apache2.2-common is the package containing the init scripts and other useful apache-related tools..